# Выборка нужных json данных в ячейке по заданному ключу Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, json

есть таблица history в которой данные хранятся в json строке. 
База данных mysql
Структура таблицы:
id - user_id - add_date - kind - data
Пример данных хранящихся в ячейке **data** в формате ключ значение:

```
{"item_title":"title","item_id":"id","item_amount":"amount","user_id":"id"}
```

пример записи с одним ключом:

```
{"ip":"000000000"}
```

Выборку этой строки сделать получается

```
$history = database::i()->history('data', '{"ip":"'.$this->request['ip'].'"}')
```

А вот с первым примером проблема, так как его нужно доставать по ключу **item_id**
При попытке осуществить выборку как с вариантом выборки ip ни к чему не произведет так как ищется полное совпадение данных.

Вопрос в том, как можно пропустить определенный кусок данных в ячейке в начале и в конце, что бы можно было искать лишь по одному ключу.
Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу с помощью оператора LIKE 
Пример решения по моему вопросу:

```
$history = database::i()->history('user_id = ?', $user_id)->where('data LIKE ?', '{"item_title":"%",%'.$id.'%');
```

для большей точности, еще включил заголовок который одинаков в этой записи.